# In scala is it acceptable to have id variables written as `_id` instead of the regular camel case notation?

Tags: coding-standards, scala, variables

In Scala is it acceptable to have id variables written as `_id` instead of the regular camel case notation?

In the code most variables respect the camel case notation. However for variables referring to id, I like to append `_id` at the end instead of `Id`. To me it makes it clearer and also different from other variables. Example:

let's say I have an object `Employee` in a case class

```
case class Employee(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, company_id: Long, job_id: Long)
```

instead of

```
case class Employee(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, companyId: Long, jobId: Long)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

> Underscores in names (_) are not actually forbidden by the compiler, but are strongly discouraged as they have special meaning within the Scala syntax.

Mutators for example use the "_=" convention;

```
def bar_=(bar: Bar) {
    ...
}
```

It's (over)used in imports;

```
import _root_.net.liftweb._
```

*From [Scala Docs: Naming Conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html)*

... and so on. The main notion is that underscores have their own unique use in Scala (as opposed to other languages, e.g. Java) and should be avoided using in variable names; saved for where appropriate.